# Chrome remote debugging is not working?

Tags: google-chrome

when i connect to my phone it shows me error ( i have latest version of chrome on mobile and laptop).
Please guide me, how to remove this error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the rule is that Chrome on desktop must be newer than Chrome on mobile.

Comment: but current desktop chrome update version is `38.0.2125.122 m (64-bit)`, i tried to update chrome but it shows `chrome up to date`

Comment: You can download a beta version of Chrome (https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html) which shows up as version 39.0.2171.62. 
Then remote debugging should work.

Comment: Hope it helps. If you have further concerns, feel free to ask.